# kuali - ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Tags: oracle, maven, kuali

When I Execute the below command:

```
mvn -X validate -Pks-db,oracle -Dks.impex.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@kuali.localdomain:1521:DB11G -Dks.impex.dba.password=Oracle123
```

I get the below exception:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.4:execute (validate-dba-config) on project ks-bundled-db: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.4:execute (validate-dba-config) on project ks-bundled-db: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Comment: sqlplus sys/Oracle123 as sysdba and sqlplus KSBUNDLED/KSBUNDLED Works fine. This user is configured in POM.xml file.

Comment: "invalid username/password", can you access the db with the credentials you pass to Maven via the -D options?

Comment: Are you assuming it will default to a particular username? Or do you need `-Dks.impex.dba.username="SYS AS SYSDBA"`?

Comment: Thanks all for suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to this document](https://wiki.kuali.org/display/STUDENTDOC/3.2+Load+Impex+Data+Via+Maven), you should be supplying the user name as well; their example is:

```
mvn validate -Pks-db,oracle -Dks.impex.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE -Dks.impex.dba.username="SYS AS SYSDBA" -Dks.impex.dba.password=<SYS password>
```

So you need to add to your command:

```
-Dks.impex.dba.username="SYS AS SYSDBA"
```

It isn't clear what you have set in your properties file or which value is needed/used; but it may be picking up your KSBUNDLED username, or the legacy MASTER name.

Comment: Thanks Alex. It really worked for me.Though i changed below wherever it was required:                                                      <properties>
                <ks.impex.username>KSBUNDLED</ks.impex.username>
                <ks.impex.password>KSBUNDLED</ks.impex.password>
 </properties>

Comment: @ICTApplication - it seems to be looking for property ks.impex.dba.username rather than ks.impex.username for this. I may be reading that document wrongly though. Glad it worked out though.

Comment: Now i am running this to load the dataset, i hope it must go well, i will keep you posted. Thanks for prompt help and answer----  mvn -X clean install -Pks-db,oracle -Dks.impex.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@kuali.localdomain:1521:DB11G -Dks.impex.dba.username="SYS AS SYSDBA" -Dks.impex.dba.password=Oracle123